# SIGTRAP does not show up if I write "cout"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am writing a Particle-In-Cell code to simulate plasma-laser interactions. The core of the code is the following (all the variables have been initialized properly before this):

```
for(int it = 0; it < Nt-1; it++)
{
        //cout << "it = " << it << endl;
        pos = pos_update(pos, vel, qm, E_P, it);
        
        vel = vel_update(pos, vel, it);
        
        rho_part = rho_part_update(rho_part, pos, qm, it);
        rho = rho_update(rho, rho_part, it);
        
        E_P = E_P_update(E_P, pos, rho, rho_part, it);
    }
}
```

As you can see `cout` is commented. If so, when executing the program it eventually stops and the debugger shows the message "Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap". The weird thing is that if I allow that "cout" line of code (which I wrote to find out in which time the code fails), then there is no error and the code works as expected. Any idea of what is happening? If you need the detailed functions

Comment: Inside the E_P_update() function there are the lines `float* auxE = new float[Ncell]` and `delete auxE`. If I comment the `delete auxE`, then there is no more SIGTRAP error. However, I still don't understand how the `cout` in the core code affects to this.

Comment: If you _do_ have a `new[]/delete/delete[]` mismatch, you should be able to coax either valgrind or your compiler's sanitizer or debug mode into telling you about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGTRAP` suggests that your C++ code has Undefined Behavior. But `SIGTRAP` is just one of the infinite ways in which Undefined Behavior can manifest itself. It's not that strange that adding another statement causes Undefined Behavior to show up in a different manner.

As for your comment, `new[]` and `delete` are primitives that should generally be avoided. `std::vector` is probably the cleaner solution. But if you do use then, then `new[]` must be paired with `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Just a question by the way - do I need to use delete[] inside a function or the allocated memory will be deleted automatically when exiting the function?

Comment: @AliEsquembreKucukalic: If you want automatic deletion at the end of a function, just use `std::vector`. You use `delete[]` when the deletion must be done manually, at some complex time in the future which the compiler cannot determine for you. This is very, very rare nowadays. In the rare cases where `vector` doesn't work, there are backup options `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` which also sidestep the need for `delete`.